# Delete pattern in string and semicolon before and/or after (R)

Tags: r, string, replace

In genomics, we often have to work with many strings of gene names that are separated by semicolons. I want to do pattern matching (find a specific gene name in a string), and then remove that from the string. I also need to remove any semicolon before or after the gene name. This toy example illustrates the problem.

```
s <- c("a;b;x", "a;x;b", "x;b", "x")
library(stringr)
str_replace(s, "x", "")
#[1] "a;b;" "a;;b" ";b"   ""
```

The desired output should be.

```
#[1] "a;b" "a;b" "b"   ""
```

I could do pattern matching for `;x` and `x;` as well and that would give me the output; but that wouldn't be very efficient. We can also use `gsub` or the `stringi` package and that would be fine as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `x` and optional `;` after it if `x` is the starting character of the string otherwise remove `x` and optional `;` before it which should cover all the cases as listed:

```
str_replace(s, "^x(;?)|(;?)x", "")
# [1] "a;b" "a;b" "b"   ""
```

Comment: Thanks. But the first element still has an extra ; at the end. "a;b;" should be "a;b".

Answer (score 1):

We can use `gsub` from `base R`

```
gsub("^x;|;?x", "", s)
#[1] "a;b" "a;b" "b"   ""
```